# Obtener los vertices de un objeto en blender con script

Tags: python, blender

mediante un script bpy en blender, quiero obtener los vertices de un objeto y guardaros en un archivo, el problema es que no se como extraer esos datos.
El código es el siguiente:

```
import bpy, os;

result = ""

for sel in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    v = sel.data.vertices
    resultado += "%s - %f\n" % (sel.name,v.vertices)
```

Exactamente me da error en el parámetro `v.vertices`

Comment: No saber cual es el error que te da hace más interesante el desafío de responder a tu pregunta. El que no incluyas datos para probar la hace un puzzle aún más interesante.

Comment: Es que justamente no me dice cual es el error en la consola, solo que ese parametro esta mal o no puedo acceder a el

Comment: Entonces. Si no muestra ningun mensaje de error... Como sabes que está ese error especifico?